# How to port my current bash history over when opening a tmux session?

Tags: bash, tmux, command-history

I often find myself in this situation:

- I start doing something in a terminal.
- I need more terminal space, so I open `tmux`.
- History is gone, even the commands I wanted to run inside tmux.

How can I port over the current bash history into a new tmux session? Ideally something I can add to tmux configuration and otherwise something I can put in an alias like `tmuxhist`.

Comment: You could always try switching to zsh, universal history in every terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`history -w; tmux` does the trick somewhat.

`alias tmuxhist='history -w; tmux'` creates an alias for it.

Unfortunately it's [not possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80473/how-do-i-run-a-shell-command-from-tmux-conf) to add commands to be executed at startup in tmux configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
shopt -s histappend
```

This solution is not specific to tmux, it'll also work with GNU screen or tabbed terminals or just opening new xterm windows. Basically, it says "append to history on every command, and make sure bash doesn't empty the history file on exit".

That also means you can open a new pane in tmux and ctrl+p to get the last command executed in the previous pane.